I am unable to move unallocated space next to my root partition in order to extend that partitions size
I am trying to move space from my home partition to my root partition. I have read many forum posts, but none have resolved my problem. I am using gparted inside Ubuntu installation flash drive.
I am able to shrink my home partition, which places the unallocated space to the right. The 'free space preceding' option in the move/resize tool is greyed out, so I am unable to create the space to the left, which would be next to the root partition which I need to extend. Also the left side arrow on the graphical resizer thing is not there, so that is not an option either.
Once I do create unallocated space to the right, I do not see any way to move the partition into that space.
I am unable to install needed programs onto my laptop until this is fixed, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Depending upon the partitioning tool, you might be able to "right drag" the home partition, but that is slooooooow. Probably quicker to backup your files and reinstall with the correct partition sizes, then restore.

Do you know of any guides to help me backup/restore? Im guessing it involves backing up personal files and config files, but I dont know the process for importing the config files to the new install. This is probably the route I will take, as no partition manager ive tried seems to be able to help me.

Actually, you really just need to backup your home partition. Then remove it and simply expand root to the size you want. then make a new partition for home, make a filesystem on it (mkfs -text4 /dev/), and restore your files (a simple rsync or cp should work).  One gotcha is some partition tools will automatically resize the filesystem in an expanded partition, and some don't.  If the filesystem size didn't expand, run sudo resize2fs /dev/ and it should expand fill the partition. Check the EFI's grub.cfg stub for the new filesystem's UUID.

@ubfan1 that looks like one answer.

Have an install media handy, just in case, and ensure your backups are up-to-date and readable, because things can go badly wrong when altering partitions.
You really just need to backup your home partition. Then remove it and simply expand root to the size you want. then make a new partition for home, make a filesystem on it:
sudo mkfs -text4 /dev/<your home>

and restore your files (a simple rsync or cp should work). One gotcha is some partition tools will automatically resize the filesystem in an expanded partition, and some don't. If the filesystem size didn't expand, run:
 sudo resize2fs /dev/<your-root-partition>

and it should expand fill the partition.  Confirm that the new resized root filesystem did not get a new UUID and of course the new home partition will have a new UUID. Use blkid to list the UUIDs:
sudo blkid

Change the old UUIDs to the new if they changed in the /etc/fstab file and if necessary, the root UUID in the EFI partition's (usually mounted at /boot/efi) /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. Rerun sudo update-grub to update the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, and check that booting still works.

You probably mean the new home filesystem will get a new UUID.

@mook765 Certainly, edited to update both in fstab.  I assumed a resize2fs would change the UUID -- appalling to think two different sized filesystems could have the same UUID!

FYI: resize2fs does not change the UUID.
